# Trying to import Levenshtein on (Jupyter ipython + windows)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to python and Anaconda and I tried to run my code which contains Levenshtein import, however, it shows me this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-896847aaaa86> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 import Levenshtein as lv
      4 import math
      5 import re

ImportError: No module named 'Levenshtein'
```

Any recommendations regarding this, I owe you tons of thanks

Comment: Where is the Levenshtein package installed? Is this directory part of the sys.path variable?

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because Anaconda does not ship with the Levenshtein package. You'll have to install it.

Usually, you want to install python packages on Jupyter Notebook by using the `conda` command. I was having trouble installing this package in particular on a Windows, however, simply because Windows Defender held out the process indefinitely.

The way I managed to install it as by using `pip` in Windows's cmd. First you have to figure out were the python executable from your Notebook is running.

In your notebook:

```
import sys
{sys.executable}
```

Copy the path the cell outputs, open the cmd. There, use the following command:

```
[PASTE THE PATH HERE] -m pip install python-levenshtein
```

After that you should be able to import Levenshtein.